# FAR manager: Alt+F10 does nothing

Tags: far-manager

I'm running FAR (File and ARchive manager) 3.0.0.5577 x64 on Windows 10.

I want to display the tree structure of the current drive.
Every other NC clone I'm aware of does this when you press Alt+F10.
However, in FAR, nothing happens. Clicking on the status bar item
(very) briefly changes the cursor, and then goes back to doing nothing.

So: how does one display said tree structure?

Answer (score 2):

Solved: type "far:config" (sans quotes) in the command line area, and change item
"Panel.Tree.TurnOffCompletely" to FALSE.
For reasons unknown to me, the default value of said item is TRUE. Odd, to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably turned off by default.
You need to toggle the flag **Panel.Tree.TurnOffCompletely** into **false** state.

To do that you need to open the config window:
On the command line type:

```
far:config
```

To quickly find that flag, press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then type "tree".

Navigate to the mentioned flag and toggle its state into false (using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key).
Exit then using the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Don't forget to save your settings (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)